# Split and display file line in bash

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script and I don't understand the return value.

My script

```
#!bin/bash
string=$(head -n 1 test.txt)
IFS=":"
read -r pathfile line <<< "$string"
echo "left"$line"right"
```

And my test.txt

```
filepath:file content
others lines
...
```

I have this return on the console.

```
rightfile content
```

The problem isn't when file only have 1 line.

I don't know why I don't have left value right to result.

Comment: Check your input file on a hex level: `xxd test1.txt`. I bet you will see a `0d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file has MSWin line ends (`\x0D\x0A`). Therefore, `\x0D` becomes part of `$line` and when printed, it moves the cursor back to the beginning, so `$line"right"` overwrites it.

Run `dos2unix` or `fromdos` on the input file to fix it.

BTW, you don't need to quote `left` and `right`. Quoting the variable might be needed, though.

```
echo left"$line"right
```